# Unexpected behaviour while using volumes in docker

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to build a very basic container, where the Working directory in the container references to one of my other directories in local disk D.

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install 

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**My Docker run command**

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app 9ffefb96a4e2
```

As shown, I'm mapping the "app" directory in the container to my present working directory. The container builds and runs properly but when I change the front end a little and refresh the URL, I see no change in the webpage. But, when I rebuild the container again and run it, I see the change incorporated, shouldn't it automatically make the change in the web page without rebuilding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is not really a solution I guess, but I realized it's an issue with windows. Apparently the networking of volumes that windows performs isn't perfect. I installed Linux, cloned the repository and it's exactly working as expected!
Let me know if someone finds a workaround for Windows users.

Answer (score 0):

Actually docker will build an image based on what you had in the moment you executed build command. If you want it to show the difference, you will need to:

1. Build the image an start again the container;
2. Use some docker container management like docker-compose (swarm, kubernetes...) and restart the container so the changes are update inside the container.

The running container will not reflect your changes because the image inside it is immutable.

Comment: Yes that's how it behaves normally, I was learning in a course that in order to prevent multiple builds, we can use the -v fang, and let the working directory in the container reference our build context outside, that way when changes are made to the source file, they would be reflected. The video in the course shows it as well.

Comment: That's really nice, didn't know about it but I'll try the see how it works. Thanks for the information!