# Can my docker instance update as I develop locally?

Tags: docker

If I run my application locally using docker-compose commands `build` the `up` I see my application running on port `http://localhost:3000` which is great. However, I'm a little confused about how I can run this setup, install additional packages into the container, etc to continue developing? Maybe I'm getting mixed up but I thought I could have this self-contained developer environment without actually having to install everything locally if that makes sense? My limited understanding of docker is that it removes the requirements for various machine setup?

I guess I'm wondering if there is a way for my running docker container to refresh/reload when there is a code change or I need to install new dependencies?

Comment: Honestly, this is way to broad. Your real problem is "my limited understanding of docker". It is a complex tool, dont expect that you can use it for real work without spending some time reading a good book or tutorial. Beyond that, the actual answer really depends. The last thing you normally do is to *manually* install anything in a running docker image. Instead, you write **build** files that ensure your docker image has all the things you need for your work. There are just too many ways to go about your requirements, especially given that we really lack understanding of their exact nature.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is fairly simple but you haven't told us what language you're using so giving you a working example that you'll find useful is pretty hard. What you need to do is create a container that can execute your program but `mount` your source/bin directories when you run it so that it sees your source/binaries, then you need a version of your development tools that can react to changes in your code.

For example, with node.js, assuming you have your `package.json` in your project root and the source under `/src` off the root, it can be done this way:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:current-buster-slim
RUN npm install -g nodemon
ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon"]
CMD ["/app/src/index.js"]
```

Put that file in your project (maybe in a directory called something like `docker`). This is a set of instructions to build a docker image based on a nodejs image on docker-hub. It installs `nodemon`, a hot-reloading utility for node.js, and instructs the image to use it. It then configures itself to run `index.js` in the `/app/src/` directory. There is an assumption that this is what you'll call the entry point for your application but it can easily be changed.

In a bash shell you can then enter the directory and issue the command:

```sh
docker build --tag node-dev .
```

where `node-dev` is the name of the image you're creating. Then, in the root of your project you can do this:

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/app node-dev
```

This creates and starts a container based on the previously built `node-dev` image, attached to the terminal, which will delete itself once it has finished executing. It mounts the current working directory (the project root in this example) into a directory in the container called `/app`.

You'll still have to run `npm install` before you first run this, to ensure that you have the right modules in your node_modules directory, but from there on in the `nodemon` application will monitor your source for changes and restart your app when it does.

A similar pattern will work with java, but hot-reloading is a little more difficult. Similar patterns exist for python and other languages.

Answer (score -1):

If you need only to install new dependencies, you can get inside the container (`docker exec -it <container name or id> bash (or sh)` and install. If these new dependencies require reload some how, you could commit your new image (creating a new image) and work with that.

If your changes are some front end files (or something like it) and you want to see the changes as you modify these files, you could use volumes with `docker run` as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524478/unexpected-behaviour-while-using-volumes-in-docker/63525282#63525282) question.

Edit:

As said in comments, the best approach would be using a Dockerfile to create a new image with those new dependencies since everything installed by `docker exec` will be lost when exit the container if not committed into a new image.

Comment: Using `docker exec` to install packages or do any other significant work inside a container isn't a best practice.  It's extremely routine to delete and recreate containers and anything you do in a `docker exec` shell will be lost once the container exits.

Comment: Yes indeed, but during development, it's possible to use `docker exec` to test new installed dependencies and then `docker commit` if this new container works. Then we can delete and recreate this new image. But it's really normal to delete containers, they are supposed to "killable". I'd recommend using Dockerfile to this, but since he said that has "limited understanting of docker", maybe `docker exec` it's a more friendly approach right now.

Comment: Or maybe the OP should address the root cause, which is "limited understanding". There are no detours in life, when somebody wants to use a complex tool for real work, then the starting point shouldnt be "establishing bad practices to workaround learning how to properly use that tool".